# Filling hole after using screw modifier

Tags: screw-modifier

I Have no idea how to fix the hole that is generated by the screw modifier automatically.

Blender version 2.93

[image: Shape created using Mesh Single Vertex]

[image: After Applying Screw Modifier]

Comment: If the top and bottom inside points are _exactly_ on the Z axis, there shouldn't be a hole.  Have you tried making sure those points have X and Y coordinates that are exactly 0?

Comment: Thanks man It worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If the top and bottom inside points are exactly on the Z-axis, there shouldn't be a hole. Have you tried making sure those points have X and Y coordinates that are exactly 0? – 
Marty Fouts
```

works exactly after setting X and Y coordinates zero.

In other cases answer given by @KickAir8p can be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Although Marty Fouts' comment is a good point, if you've already converted this to a mesh and applied the Screw modifier, then I'd suggest you go into edit mode, select all the edges around the hole, and use Grid Fill.

Comment: I tried to do that by referring to other tutorials but every time I select the edge in edit mode it only selects the source edges and not a complete set of edges.

I can see the object is completely selected in Object mode , in edit mode its only selecting source edges

Comment: Sorry, what I recommended should work if you've both converted this to a mesh and applied the Screw Modifier -- then if you go into Edit mode you should be able to select all of the edges around the hole and use Grid Fill (I've edited my answer to clarify this a bit).  If you haven't done either of these then you probably want to go with Marty's comment.

Comment: I Had a problem with X and Y  coordinates  of vertex , This might help as well If I encounter anything more Thanks for your Answer.